# 12V PWM signal circuit configuration

Tags: pwm, 12v

[image]

I am a student learning motors. The motor I want to make requires a circuit diagram. The input 12V PWM signal goes into 5V LEVEL, and the LDO 5V MCU 5 OR 3.3 V goes into the motor driver and operates as a motor. The output must also be 12V. ADD 100HZ TO

To explain again, input to 12V motor 10~50% CW rotation output output duty 20~100%
Input 51%~90% CCW rotation output output duty is the same. The lower right is the value to be obtained.

I have to make a circuit diagram and explain it, but it's so difficult that I can't do it.

Comment: A small change of the PWM input duty from 50% = 100% CW to 51% = 20% CCW can destroy the motor driver. To me this does not look like a useful concept. I would assign 0% PWM to 100% CW, 50% PWM to motor stop and 100% PWM to 100 % CCW. Then you have a smooth change in direction and no dangeous currents in the driver stage.

Comment: I just set the values arbitrarily to make a circuit diagram and explain it. It does not actually drive the motor!! Thank you for answer